# how to display data from database using yii framework

Tags: php, yii

I'm new to yii..I created one form that contains name,password and role.

I want to display all three data in view page.I'm using encode method but it display only one field.can anyone helpme..

```
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->fieldname); ?>
```

it display one field name but I want to display all three..

Help me...

Comment: is there any possible for single line command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write above code for each field separately:

```
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->fieldname); ?>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->fieldpassword); ?>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->fieldrole); ?>
```

Note that, I suppose your fields are `fieldpassword` and `fieldrole`.

**Update:**

This is not possible to write only one command. All these 3 commands is required. But if you mean **number of lines**, you can do this:

```
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->fieldname)."-". CHtml::encode($data->fieldpassword)."-".CHtml::encode($data->fieldrole);
```

Comment: You are welcome. This is not possible, you have "3" fields, so you need to write one line for each field. I recommend you to learn more about yii widgets, like CGridView, CListView, etc. Also I think a sample yii CRUD is the good resource for learning. You can generate a sample crud using Gii tools.

Comment: thank you so much hamed..can you give some links to create a form with create,update and delete options.sorry for my poor language..thank you

Comment: You are welcome. You can use Gii CRUD generator. [Here is the related link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app#implementing-crud-operations). I believe that the best tutorial is yii official documentation.